# How to decide maxIdle properties in DB connection pooling configuration?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, tomcat-jdbc

I am using tomcat jdbc for DB connection pooling. recently i have increased my **maxActive** property after frequent **connection pool exhaust issue** (when application under heavy load) so decided to increased the **maxActive** property by 50% after performing multiple load test to check the impact on CPU and memory.

but i observed that there is one **maxIdle** property also which i haven't modified so should i increase this one also  and if yes then how to decide this number.any suggestion.

Comment: "_I am using tomcat jdbc for DB connection pooling_" - do you mean Tomcat DBCP 2 (Tomcat's default pool provider)? If so, have you looked at the [settings definitions](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) and additional notes in the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)? The `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` setting may also be worth checking. It's unlikely we can give you any advice about what specific values you should use. (You can try using different pool providers, also.)

Comment: Worth reading this blog on [pool sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) and also this on [fixed pool design](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1395487594923-5797135.post@n5.nabble.com) and this on [minimumIdle=maximumPoolSize](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#gear-configuration-knobs-baby)